# Can someone explain what routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); is need for?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following in my MVC routing file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Can someone explain to me what these are used for? Also do they need to appear before the MVC and WebAPI routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route with the pattern {resource}.axd/{*pathInfo} is included to prevent requests for the Web resource files such as WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd from being passed to a controller.

The favicon route is to prevent the favicon to be mapped to a route.

Read more here:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)
[Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)